# How can I save only specific fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I update my Usuario form I have a problem the password field is save in blank but I want to save only specific fields and don't affect password field.

I try this

```
if usuario.contrasenia == '':
            form.save(update_fields=['nombre', 'correo_electronico', 'direccion', 'usuario', 'id_perfil', 'fecha_modificacion'])
```

but I get this

```
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'
```

The main problem is that I don't know how override the save method to save only specific fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`update_fields` is an argument to a model's `save()` method, not to the form's `save()` method.

You can use `obj = form.save(commit=False)` to get the model instance with the updated fields, then call `obj.save(update_fields=...)`.